# Flask RESTful Destroy User Token

Tags: python, rest, flask, restful-authentication, flask-restful

I am setting up a Flask-RESTful service and have user authentication working. The method that I'm using is:

```
def generate_auth_token(username, expiration=600):
    gen_serial = Serializer(secret_key, expires_in=expiration)
    return gen_serial.dumps({'username': username})
```

I pass the token to the user as follows:

```
class token(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]
    def post(self):
        username = g.user
        return_token = generate_auth_token(username)
        return {'token':return_token.decode()}, 200
```

And the token is then verified as such so that it does not need to be stored server side:

```
def verify_auth_token(auth_token):
    serial = Serializer(secret_key)
    try:
        data = serial.loads(auth_token)
    except SignatureExpired:
        return None 
    except BadSignature:
        return None 
    serial_user = data['username']
    return serial_user
```

This seems to work well, however I am unsure how to logout the user before the expiration is expired without storing the token serverside. My thought was to pass back a garbage token when the user elects to logout, but I don't think this is an elegant or secure solution.

Any tips would be really helpful!

Comment: Is this a user-initiated logout or a server initiated one?

Comment: I'm aiming for user initiated. The goal is for the user to click logout when they're done working, otherwise the token will expire after a time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a garbage token simply encode no data:

```
def generate_auth_token(username=None, expiration=600):
    gen_serial = Serializer(secret_key, expires_in=expiration)
    data = {'username': username} if username is not None else {}
    return gen_serial.dumps(data)
```

Then you can have an `invalidate` endpoint that requires a login and returns a token without a username:

```
def invalidate(self):
    return_token = generate_auth_token()
    return {'token':return_token.decode()}, 200
```

At that point, you can just handle the possibly missing username field:

```
def verify_auth_token(auth_token):
    serial = Serializer(secret_key)
    try:
        data = serial.loads(auth_token)
    except SignatureExpired:
        return None 
    except BadSignature:
        return None 
    serial_user = data.get('username')
    return serial_user
```

Comment: Thanks! Pending a little testing I think this should work great.

Comment: @Sean: maybe I did not understand the OP question, but how is your solution invalidating a valid token before it expires? I can get a valid token, then call the `invalidate()` endpoint, and the original token will still be valid and usable until it expires. Right?

Comment: @Miguel - correct.  The client wants to get rid of its token, so it *could* just drop it, but the OP wanted to be able to "trade in" the token explicitly.  But a malicious client or man-in-the-middle could still use the valid token until it expires.